# Open popup when click on marker

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I have this code :

```
popupIsOpen = false;
const marker: Marker = this.map.addMarkerSync(markerData);
marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe(this.markerClick);

markerClick(params: any) {
        this.popupIsOpen = !this.popupIsOpen;
        const marker: Marker = params[1] as Marker;
}
```

The template :

```
<ion-content>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</ion-content>
<div [ngClass]="{'overlay': popupIsOpen, 'hidden': !popupIsOpen}">
    <ion-card>
        <ion-card-content>
            <ion-button (click)="popupIsOpen=!popupIsOpen">close</ion-button>
             Content
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</div>
```

The popup is not displayed when I click on marker. What I’m doing wrong ? Thx in advance.

Comment: Do you have any error in the console?

Comment: No, but if I initialize `popupIsOpen = true;` the popup is displayed on the map, and after that if I click on the marker the popup dissapear and no more displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google map API events are not monkey patched by zone.js and therefore are not running in the ngZone. You should manually re-enter the zone using `ngZone.run()`:

```
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

markerClick(params: Marker[]) {
  this.ngZone.run(() => {
    this.popupIsOpen = !this.popupIsOpen;
    const marker: Marker = params[1] as Marker;
  });
}
```

---

There is also a possibility you are losing the `this` context, because you are not binding the events properly. There are several options, one is to use the anonymous arrow function notation when binding:

```
marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe((params) => this.markerClick(params));
```